# How to rename files in linux shell using regexp?

Tags: linux, shell, batch-processing, file-rename, batch-rename

I have some files:

```
/var/www/media/0001/0001_123456_12.jpg
/var/www/media/0002/0002_123456_12.jpg
/var/www/media/0003/0003_123456_12.jpg
```

and I want to rename them to:

```
/var/www/media/0001/0001_test.jpg
/var/www/media/0002/0002_test.jpg
/var/www/media/0003/0003_test.jpg
```

My idea was to find the first `_`, remove the rest of the file until the `.` then add `test`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /var/www/media/ -name \*.jpg -exec sh -c '
  a=$(echo {} | sed s/_123456_/_/);
  [ "$a" != "{}" ] && mv "{}" "$a" '
```

You find all jpg files in the `/var/www/media` and run for each file the command:

```
a=$(echo {} | sed s/_123456_/_/)
[ "$a" != "{}" ] && mv "{}" "$a"
```

After this command, the `a` variable has rewritten name of the file inside:

```
a=$(echo {} | sed s/_123456_/_/)
```

The we compare the `a` variable and the realname (`{}`), and they are not equal
the file must be renamed.

Comment: what about if `123456` number is unknown? maybe it is `123457` or `125556`

Comment: you mean that there can be any digits?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [solution in perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=277174) that allows you to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install the `mmv` package, then these operations become easy. With `mmv`, you can do what you want with:

```
cd /var/www/media
mmv '*/*_123456_*.jpg' '#1/#2_test.jpg'
```

Here is the mmv manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/mln.1.html